# JavaScript searching for a user based on their username?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I've created a function that uses getJSON to retrieve a data set found on an API website of registered Github Users

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!---->
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var user = $('#search').val();
                $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/" + user)
                    .done(function(data) {
                        var br = "<br>";
                        var p = $("<p id='users'></p>");
                             
                            var name = "Username: "+ user.login + br;
                            var pic = "Avatar Picture:" + br + "<img src='"+user.avatar_url+"'/>" +br;
                            var homeURl = "Homepage URL: "+"<a href='"+user.html_url+"'>"+user.html_url+"</a>" +br;
                            var location = "Location: "+"Null" +br;
                            var admin = "Admin: "+user.site_admin;
                            p.append("<p>"+ name  + pic + homeURl + location + admin +"</p>");
                        
                        $("#results").empty().append(p);
                    })
                    .fail(function(jqXHR) {
                        console.log("Error: " + jqXHR.status);
                    })
                    .always(function() {
                        console.log("Random Users Request finished");
                    });
                });
                
        </script>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <input id="search" type = "text">
        <button>Search</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can tell I have began to modify it so that instead of displaying all users it only displayers the user that has been searched

```
var user = $('#search').val();
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/" + user)
```

This snippet of code grabes the username entered in the text area and passes it to the getJSON method in the Url. An example URL is "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo", thus if the user enters "mojombo" then their profile would appear

This function is accessed via a button

```
<input id="search" type = "text">
<button>Search</button>
```

However when you search for the example user, in fact any user no data is displayed and a blank screen remains

Comment: Why have you changed your question?

Comment: Have you checked the console? Do you get error messages?

Comment: @connexo I did not change it, I just added your edit about the button

Comment: @user16973340 are you passing the valid value in the search textbox?

Comment: You either have to add `defer` and/or `async` to your script or move it to the bottom of the body. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zy2x3en1/) is a working example. Next you have to replace `user` with `data` in `success`.

Comment: @user16973340 as this is a open API , first check in the browser directly like https://api.github.com/users/{which value you want to enter in search textbox}. If you are getting the valid response then debug your code using browser debugger.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, pick the correct answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not connected your function to the button.

As it stands, it runs before the user has typed anything into the search field (thus requesting `"https://api.github.com/users/"` because `user` at that time is an empty string) , and won't react at all to a button click.

Instead of just

```
$(function(){
   /* code */ 
});
```

do

```
$(function(){ 
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        /* code that runs when button is clicked */
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes thankyou, however even with this edit it still does not search

Comment: If you're on windows, open the developer tools of your browser (usually F12), and check for errors on the console tab. If there are non, change to the network tab, and while it is open, perform a search to see if the request is being issued and what response you get.

Comment: Theres no error on the console tab and from what I can see there are no requests

Comment: I've corrected my answer, it should work now. The issue was that without the `$function() {` part jQuery cannot find the button, and thus it won't bind the click listener function.